# WMAppManifest.xml file for deploying vcREG

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I've been trying to deploy vcREG to my Windows Phone using the deployment app installed while installing Windows Phone SDK. I downloaded the app over the internet and I wanted to interop unlock my phone using it. But, while installing, it gives me an error, to fix capabilities in the WMAppManifest.xml file. Please help me by providing the correct file with all capabilities fixed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take a [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and have a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It might be worth including the error message that you are getting and maybe a screenshot if it helps.

Comment: ask here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-phone-8/development/xap-vcreg-lumia-reg-editor-live-interop-t3135326